# Visual Studio JavaScript resources not available on build

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and working a SharePoint host application based on AngualrJS.

After a merge with another developer, witch was not fun, resources added to the scripts folder are reporting NOT FOUND 404 when the application is deployed.

all other resources are working with no issue and the script definitions are all the same reference.

I am reasonably new to Visual Studio and I not sure what I have broken and why only certain files just don't seem to be syncing or available online.

Comment: Check if there are excluded from the project, or do the manual copy paste on the server.

Comment: Check the path of scripts, might be you are using / and created a virtual directory with some name, in that case it will not work